# Kafka - Confluent s3 connect - Connector fails to connect to s3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm trying to build a demo application where I read into a kafka topic from a public source and write this data into s3. Exactly as indicated in this link - https://www.confluent.fr/blog/apache-kafka-to-amazon-s3-exactly-once.

My s3 connector fails connecting to s3 even though I have valid credentials as part of my environment variables and as part of my ~/.aws/credentials file.

I know that the credentials are fine, as I'm able to access the bucket using awscli.

Tried two ways of configuring the AWS provider (as part of the connector.properties)

**com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain
and,
com.amazonaws.auth.EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider**

When run with the DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain, the connector seems to be trying to connect with secret and access keys which are not what is set in environment variables (and ~/.aws/credentials). and, fails with the error :

> org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting
>   WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception
>
> com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The AWS Access Key
>   Id you provided does not exist in our records. (Service: Amazon S3;
>   Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId; Request ID:
>   8FF2B58289B657EA), S3 Extended Request ID:
>   N73Jdmn39Rwp/eet4WWAj0CiRCqq2Cmh/ILf5F7Hxnj/P7djg1//FU9hb75ImVQWAf9fnGqi51E=\n\tat
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1586)

When run with the EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider, Its not able to see the environment variables. and, connector fails with the following error:

> "trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException:
>   com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from
>   environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and
>   AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))\n\tat
>   io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkTask.start(S3SinkTask.java:118)

How do I get the s3 connector to see my environment variables??